# Как сделать так, чтобы перенаправил на следующую страницу только после заполнения поля телефона(до конца - +7 (xxx) xxx xx xx)

Tags: jquery

```js
// маска ввода телефона

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  [].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('.tel'), function(input) {
  var keyCode;
  function mask(event) {
      event.keyCode && (keyCode = event.keyCode);
      var pos = this.selectionStart;
      if (pos < 3) event.preventDefault();
      var matrix = "+7 (___) ___ ____",
          i = 0,
          def = matrix.replace(/\D/g, ""),
          val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, ""),
          new_value = matrix.replace(/[_\d]/g, function(a) {
              return i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++) || def.charAt(i) : a
          });
      i = new_value.indexOf("_");
      if (i != -1) {
          i < 5 && (i = 3);
          new_value = new_value.slice(0, i)
      }
      var reg = matrix.substr(0, this.value.length).replace(/_+/g,
          function(a) {
              return "\\d{1," + a.length + "}"
          }).replace(/[+()]/g, "\\$&");
      reg = new RegExp("^" + reg + "$");
      if (!reg.test(this.value) || this.value.length < 5 || keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58) this.value = new_value;
      if (event.type == "blur" && this.value.length < 5)  this.value = ""
  }

  input.addEventListener("input", mask, false);
  input.addEventListener("focus", mask, false);
  input.addEventListener("blur", mask, false);
  input.addEventListener("keydown", mask, false)

});

});
```

```html
<form action="yes/thanks.html" method="GET">
   <input class="profit__form-name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required minlength="4" maxlength="15">
   <input class="profit__form-tel tel" type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="+7 (XXX) XXX XX XX" required> 
   <input class="profit__form-site" type="text" name="site" placeholder="Сайт или соц. сеть">
   <button class="profit__form-btn popup-btn" type="submit">Оставить заявку</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё, я понял, надо было просто поменять последнюю строчу js if (event.type == "blur" && this.value.length < 5)  this.value = ""      на      if (event.type == "blur" && this.value.length < 17)  this.value = ""